# Vue js: Como imprimir un array de objetos relacionado a un checkbox?

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js, objeto, checkbox

Estoy intentando imprimir un array de objetos relacionado a un checkbox.
Por ejemplo: checkbox cars cuando es seleccionado debe imprimir el array de cars.
Si no hay ningun checkbox seleccionado se imprimen todos los arrays

Este es mi codigo:

```
<template>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div>
        <input id="boundingBox" type="checkbox" value="boundingBoxes" v-model="checkboxes">
        <label for="boundingBox"> i1 </label>

        <input id="tree" type="checkbox" value="trees" v-model="checkboxes">
        <label for="tree"> i2 </label>

        <input id="last" type="checkbox" value="cars" v-model="checkboxes">
        <label for="last"> i3 </label>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <h2> list: </h2>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in checkboxes" :key="index">
          <p>{{ item[index].name }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
    let boundingBoxes = [
      {
        name: "bounding box",
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        name: "bounding box",
        color: "orange"
      }
    ];

    let trees = [
    {
      name: "tree",
      color: "green"
    },
    {
      name: "tree",
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      name: "tree",
      color: "yellow"
    }
  ];

  let cars = [
    {
      name: "car",
      color: "black"
    },
    {
      name: "car",
      color: "blue"
    },
    {
      name: "car",
      color: "brown"
    }
  ]

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        checkboxes:[
          boundingBoxes,
          trees,
          cars
        ],
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

En la etiqueta script estan los arrays a imprimir.
checkboxes v-model="" tienen el nombre del array correspondiente.
El div debajo de los labels e inputs es donde se tienen que imprimir los arrays.
Ahora se imprimen los arrays pero los checkboxes no funcionan.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Falta el código que has intentado?

Comment: Acabo de conseguir un avance, ahora actualizo el codigo, ya intente tantas cosas que por eso subi algo limpio. Ahi agregue nuevo codigo, logre que se impriman los arrays pero los cheboxes no me funcionan.

Comment: logre que recorra bien, lo unico que me falta es que filtre con los checkbox que no lo puedo lograr, actualizado en el codigo como muestro los nombres

Comment: ¿De casualidad no te sería de utilidad tener una variable adicional para saber cuál checkbox está marcado?

Comment: si, podria ser util para validar al momento de hacer el print, pero donde se le setearia el valor a esa variable? y que pasa en el caso se que haya mas de un checkbox tildado?

Comment: Ni idea, sin una descripción clara del escenario, sin alguna prueba tangible de lo que quieres realizar, ¿cómo podemos colaborar? Aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.